# Is this routine for determining the epsilon of a Double 100% valid?

Tags: c#, algorithm, mathematics

This algorithm is intended to determine the epsilon of a given double precision number. As numbers increase in value, their accuracy decreases. This algorithm will return the smallest increment / decrement possible at any given value.

Given the way floating point numbers are structured, is there logically any situation where this algorithm won't work? It has worked fine for whatever numbers I've thrown at it.

```
public enum EZeroDirection { TowardsZero, AwayFromZero };

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
private struct DL
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal double D;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal long L;
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns the dynamic epsilon of this Double. If the value is NaN or ±Inf, or the initial result overflows, the result will be null.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>See (http://bit.ly/10KS2wo)</remarks>
/// <param name="dir">Determines if the epsilon is calculated from the delta of its next value towards zero or away from zero. Choose the direction 
/// the value moves in. Note: EZeroDirection.TowardsZero allows proper processing of Double.MaxValue and Double.MinValue.</param>
/// <returns>Double?</returns>
public static Double? DynamicEpsilon(this Double a, EZeroDirection dir = EZeroDirection.TowardsZero)
{
    if (!double.IsNaN(a) && a != double.NegativeInfinity && a != double.PositiveInfinity)
    {
        DL dl = new DL();
        dl.D = a;
        dl.L -= ((dir == EZeroDirection.TowardsZero) ? 1 : -1);

        if (!double.IsNaN(dl.D))
        {
            return Math.Abs(a - dl.D);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation or a link to explain what this is supposed to do?  And/or sample input.  I get 0 no matter what I pass in.

Comment: How are you inspecting what you get back? try pass in something like 1E+100, which will give you back a large number.

Comment: I ported and adapted this from C, so I don't have a link to how it works (although the remark shows the source of where it came from, which has an extended discussion on the topic).

Comment: Ah, I'd broken it in adding it to LINQpad.  I'm getting results now, although I don't know what they mean.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? In most cases, the exact precision of `double` shouldn't matter to you.

Comment: In most cases, yes. I have specialized bucketing functions and range processing that requires this.

Comment: This is the C# version of C++'s union, which isn't directly supported by C#.  The `FieldOffset` attributes cause `D` and `L` to refer to the same memory location.  It seems to work by using the `long` representation to add/subtract one starting from the least significant bit.  Maybe you knew all this already.  It *seems* like this should always work, but I'm not an IEEE754 expert.

Comment: @recursive yes, this is what I know. Unfortunately, I'm not an IEEE754 expert either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a != double.NegativeInfinity && a != double.PositiveInfinity
```

This could be simplified to just `double.IsInfinity(a)`. Though as far as I know, it is correct. I was worried that there may be more values representing infinity, like there are for `NaN`, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

---

Otherwise, your method seems to work to me in all edge cases, including +/-0, `double.MaxValue` and `double.Epsilon` (though you should write unit tests for these just in case). In the case of +/-0 and `TowardsZero`, `D` will become `NaN`, so your method returns `null`, which I think is correct behavior.

Comment: Thanks @svick. I did test all edge cases (except -0, which I don't know how to generate). Thanks for the IsInfinity tip.

Comment: Per this article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) one may "safely assume" that the endiansess is the same for integers and FP numbers, so I *think* this code should work on both platforms.

Comment: @IanC I assumed that IEEE 754 did specify endianness. I removed that part from my answer.